# How do I configure zone file so that both, foo.com and www.foo.com work?

Tags: domain

Currently, I simply have

> www 10800 IN A xx.xxx.xxx.xxx

and with this, www.foo.com works, but not foo.com.

Comment: Could we see the rest of the zone file?  It's difficult to say how exactly to do this without seeing the structure of the zonefile.

Answer (score 4):

Your DNS servers sees www.foo and foo.com as 2 completely separate Domains. Due to this you also need to add an A record for just foo.com also like

> Foo.com. IN A xxx.xx.x.x

Where xx.x.x.x is the same IP as www.

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the quick response. Is this as same as adding a CNAME? If not, what's the difference?

Comment: No, a cname would be for setting blah.example.com to forward to blah.othersite.net. You don't have An A record for foo.com only www.foo.com so thats why only 1 works. you need to add a A record for foo.com like foo.com IN A (IPhere). It should look like www.foo.com except there should be no www. on it.

Comment: Small clarification: You'll need a dot after foo.com, as "foo.com. IN A xxx.xx.x.x"  Otherwise you are creating a record for "foo.com.foo.com."

Answer (score 2):

Generally you should make your `www` address a CNAME for your real server name in dns:

```
WWW IN CNAME server
```

then when you do a dns lookup of `example.com`, `server.example.com` and `www.example.com` the result should be the same IP address in all cases.

Then (assuming you use apache) in the main section of your httpd.conf you should have:

```
ServerName server.example.com:80
UseCanonicalName off
```

so that requesting hosts can indicate the name they are trying to connect to and the server will always respond properly.

Comment: Hm Jacob you are right, my answer may be a bit outdated.  Looking at the googles it seems like cnames are less efficient.

Comment: Jacob, please expand about why vhosts won't work. I took that config from a server that is running name-based vhosts.

Comment: Jacob, that doesn't make any sense whatsoever. The server hosting the websites sees an HTTP Host: header provided by the client. It doesn't care how the client found the IP address it's connecting to -- that's totally irrelevant information.

Comment: Sorry I typed the wrong thing, Vhosts will work but Cnames cause 2 lookups to be made to the server so thats why A records are better

Answer (score 2):

I typically do the following:

`foo.com. A [IP]` and then `www CNAME foo.com.`

(so that you don't repeat the IP twice)

Comment: Cname causes 2 lookups at the server.not very efficant

Comment: I suppose so, in that case having two A records would work also. But it is a DNS server, using CNAMES I would assume is only marginally less efficient.